# Как скрыть инфо сообщения при переходе по меню?

Tags: jquery

Ситуиация следующая:
При переходе по меню, отображается соответствующая секция

```
// Bind the navigation menu links
$("#linkHome").click(showHomeView);
$("#linkLogin").click(showLoginView);
$("#linkLogout").click(logoutUser);
```

При авторизация или выхода с акаунта есть соответсвующее сообщение а так же при ошибке авторизации:

```
function showInfo(message) {
    $('#infoBox').text(message);
    $('#infoBox').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#infoBox').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
}

function showError(errorMsg) {
    $('#errorBox').text("Error: " + errorMsg);
    $('#errorBox').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#errorBox').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Подскажите как убрать сообщение $('#errorBox').hide() если в момент отображения пользователь переходит на другую секцию, например Home Page.

Comment: добавить `$("#infoBox, #errorBox").hide()` в обработчики переходов?

Comment: $("#linkHome").click(showHomeView, $("#infoBox, #errorBox").hide());
Вот так?
Так не отрабатывает.

Comment: `$("#linkHome").click(function(e){ showHomeView.call(this, e); ("#infoBox, #errorBox").hide(); });`

Comment: Так тоже не получается. Так же исчезает через 3 сек, как обычно.

Comment: это Вы неправильно код скопировали

Comment: Еще раз скопировал, результат тот же к сожелению...

Comment: Вы можете создать работающий образец Вашего кода, отредактировав вопрос используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода на ...".